# Averaging gridded data with missing values

Tags: modeling, missing-data, biostatistics

I would like to use various parameters of remote sensing data (i.e. chorlophyl, sea-surface temperature, wind stress, etc.) as covariates in a species distribution model.

I have sightings data, including sighting effort, collected from a number of scientific cruises over a two month period.

My idea was to average environmental data for the entire sighting period, treat all sightings as having been collected simultaneously, with the 2 month average of values used as the covariates.

Given the nature of remote-sensing data, there are numerous missing values due to clouds, etc., so if I were to average the data I would need to omit any cell that had no value for >= 1 day of data. This results in a small fraction of the data, and just doesn't seem like a good way of doing things.

How can I obtain statistically consistent averaged estimates of parameters in the presence of missing data in remote sensor output?

**Update:**
Sighting effort is evaluated as the time taken before an observation is made. The more time taken for a sighting the higher the effort made to obtain the sighting. I could also use the distance covered before sighting rather than time.

Comment: Can you define sighting effort and how this influences the perceived number or likelihood of spotting a species? Are you taking advantage of the geological nature of these data (i.e. using neighboring values to infer the distribution of values in close by cells)?

Comment: Updated. Thank you Adam. Once having time averaged data, I did plan to re-sample the data to a uniform grid using nearest-neighbor (or another geologically friendly method) interpolation. But is this applicable with interpolating across daily values, rather than spatial ones?